# How to pass multiple checkbox values from view to controller (using code igniter frame work)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have tried to learn CodeIgniter framework using tutorial provided by website and I'm very much new to php and I may be asking a foolish question.
 I tried to pass checkbox status values from View to controller(get the status of check box is checked or not), it was displayed following error msg.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: controllers/Todos.php
>
> Line Number: 29

When I trace in the controller ,  it is due to foreach loop initialization. Then I echo the

```
echo $completed_todos; 
echo $completed_todos[0];
echo $completed_todos[1]; — No value;
```

what I think is ,it does not pass all the checkbox values to the controller.

In View I have used following codes :
(index.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simple CodeIgniter App - Todos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">

<?php echo form_open('todos/update_completed'); ?>

<h1>Todos</h1>

<div class="list-group">
<?php foreach ($todos as $todo) { ?>
<div class="list-group-item clearfix">
<?php
echo form_checkbox('completed', $todo->id, $todo->completed);
?>
<?php echo $todo->task; ?>

</div>
```

in controller I used below codes

Todos controller code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Todos extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();

// Load the todo model to make it available 
// to *all* of the controller's actions 
$this->load->model('Todo_model');
$this->load->helper('form'); 
}

public function update_completed() {

$completed_todos = $this->input->post('completed');
echo $completed_todos;
foreach ($completed_todos as $todo_id) {
echo 'The todo with id = ' . $todo_id
. ' is marked as completed.<br>';
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you want to get the value of multiple checkbox so you need to put in a array. But you have tried simple string and use it in a foreach loop that's why it gives an error.

Please check the below code.

**index.php (View File)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple CodeIgniter App - Todos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Todos</h1>
        <?php echo form_open('todos/update_completed'); ?>
            <div class="list-group">
                <?php foreach ($todos as $todo) { ?>
                    <div class="list-group-item clearfix">
                        <?php echo form_checkbox('completed[]', $todo->id, $todo->completed); ?>
                        <?php echo $todo->task; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <?php echo form_close();
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Todos (Controller File)**

```
public function update_completed() {
   $completed_todos = $this->input->post('completed');
   // No need to echo $completed_todos. If you want then please do below line.
   // var_dump($completed_todos);
   foreach ($completed_todos as $todo_id) {
      echo 'The todo with id = ' . $todo_id. ' is marked as completed.<br>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanksss a lotttt  @parth Viramgama. Its worked. ohh I have defined String in the view instead of array. that 's the issue. Again Thank you very much for your kind Assistance!